# compact framework C#: listView sub item

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-ce

I have to change the fore color of Listview Subitem in listview .

I m using WM6 C#, can  u plze help me out. Hw can change the colors of Subitems indivudally?

Plz help me...

Thanks in Advance

Comment: @L.B the ForeColor property does not exist `System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem' does not contain a definition for 'ForeColor'`

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to custom draw the items.  [Christian Helle has an example here](http://christian-helle.blogspot.com/2009/10/listview-custom-drawing-in-netcf.html) (it's way too long to post back here).

Answer (score 0):

I wanted something like this in my app, but Mobile screens are small. It worked better to set the entire [ListViewItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)'s [BackColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.backcolor%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) property:

```
private void ChangeLviColor(ListViewItem lvi, Color color) {
  if (lvi.BackColor != color) {
    lvi.BackColor = color;
  }
}
```

FYI: Both of the links above will take you to some great sample code.

Of special note, be aware of this remark: *"If you want to use the same background color for all subitems of an item, set the [UseItemStyleForSubItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.useitemstyleforsubitems%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) property to true. This will cause the colors and fonts specified for the item to be used for all subitem text."*